# Differences between もの こと and の

Tags: grammar, nuances

What is the differecne between, lets say those sentences?

> 面白いものを教えてください

> 面白いことを教えてください

> 面白いのを教えてください

Answer (score 1):

もの is used for tangible objects. 面白いもの could refer to some interesting object.

こと is used for intangible objects such as concepts. 面白いこと could refer to some interesting concept.

の is used to say, for your example "interesting one." Sometimes, こと and の and transposable.

Of course, there is more nuance to all three, but what I said should explain your sentence:

> ”Please tell me the interesting one/‘part.’”

Comment: thanks for your help, but im afraid to say that you are missing something a little. もの is basically this: 空間のある部分を占め、人間の感覚でとらえることのできる形をもつ対象。which is correct, tangible object, but it has also other meaning 人間が考えることのできる形のない対象。which basically means, object that has no shape, yet human can think of. thats why i asked, it all seems to similar to me, both こと and もの as well as の can be intangible stuff. (site i got the definiton from: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%89%A9_%28%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%29/)

Comment: @sieman I have never seen that. I suppose the level of distinction depends on where you are going with Japanese. In colloquial Japanese, I suppose it relates to the use of もの which reduces to もん. In HEXL/ヒール (歌), they say 「うらめしや」的なもんも, which I suppose is not a tangible object, but RELATES to a tangible object or concept. You can grasp a ghost as a concept in your mind, but not a concept such as human knowledge or logic, which is fundamentally mental; I would imagine in the latter こと would be used reasonably. Ultimately, I suppose it does not matter what is used, as long as you are understood.

Comment: well, now you at least see it, as the definition says, もの is also used for concepts. otherwise i wouldnt be asking this.